# Google Artifact Registry mirroring

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-artifact-registry

I'm using GCP Artifact registry to store my artifacts (docker repo, helm chart and etc.). I have another GCP project where I want to have GCP artifact registry with the same artifacts.

Google Artifact Registry doesn't have any embedded mechanism for that. The only solution I found is to use third-party tools. But there is no common tool for different types of artifacts (python packages, helm charts, docker images).

How do you solve this problem?

Comment: Are you talking about [`gcrane`](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/copy-from-gcr#copy-gcrane)? if not which tool you are using?

Comment: https://github.com/AliyunContainerService/image-syncer for example.

Comment: Have you tried [`gcrane`](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/copy-images#gcrane-copy) which is a direct tool to copy images?

Comment: No, but I don't think it's too important to use any specific tool to copy images

What I'm looking for is probably a tool that could work with different types of artifacts in GAR. I don't want to use  different tools for different types of artifacts.

Comment: I have also tried to figure out any direct tool for this but unable to find.. Let's see any experts can answer your question. As an additional try you may contact google support and see whether you can get any help there...